# Problems with installing ACE on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, ubuntu-11.10, ace

I own Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-18-server x86_64) and I am Trying to instal Single ACE 6.1.1 with this manual: http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html#unix_traditional

Installation has change since version 6.0.7 I think so it makes some errors after I do command "make" here is he error and I hope somebody can help me:

```
g++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -ggdb -pthread -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/opt/ace/ACE_wrappers -D__ACE_INLINE__ -I../../..  -Wl,-E -L/opt/ace/ACE_wrappers/lib -L.  -L../../../lib  -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -o taoout .obj/test.o .obj/tao.o -lACE -ldl -lrt
.obj/test.o: In function `main':
/opt/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/test.cpp:28: undefined reference to `in_word_set(char const*, unsigned int)'
/opt/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/test.cpp:28: undefined reference to `in_word_set(char const*, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [taoout] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests'
make: *** [taoinset] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you tried using `configure` script instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands like:

```
make clean
```

Solved this issue - but you have to delete build folder and re-done installation process but it works after :) Took me some time to solve but now it is ok.

Comment: usually `make clean` and `make` solves most of the compilation and linking problems. but i am facing the **same** problem in ACE 6.1.9 and it is not going away after `make clean`. any suggestions

Comment: i also have a same problem, but i am confused which build folders should i delete? and where should i run make clean command? can u elaborate.

Comment: I just did make clean and make from ACE_wrappers/ace and generated libACE.so